# How to make a utf-8 report?

Tags: birt

My report does not write exactly accentuated letters ( french ) , so there are unreadable characters displayed on the report. The runReport.php file is :

```
<?php

define("ROOT_PATH", "../");

require_once ROOT_PATH  . 'config.inc.php';
require_once("java/Java.inc");

class runReport {

    function runReport($report, $param, $output) {

      $pth = "http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
      $path_parts = pathinfo($pth);
      $imageURLPrefix = $path_parts['dirname'] ."/images/";

      session_start(); 
      $here = getcwd();

      $ctx = java_context()->getServletContext();
      $birtReportEngine =        java("org.eclipse.birt.php.birtengine.BirtEngine")->getBirtEngine($ctx);
      java_context()->onShutdown(java("org.eclipse.birt.php.birtengine.BirtEngine")->getShutdownHook());

      try{
            $thereport = $birtReportEngine->openReportDesign(RP_REPORT.$report);
            $task = $birtReportEngine->createRunAndRenderTask($thereport);
            $task->setParameterValue("province", new java("java.lang.Integer", read_post_int("province"));
            $taskOptions = new java("org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.HTMLRenderOption");
            $outputStream = new java("java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream");
            $taskOptions->setOutputStream($outputStream);
            $taskOptions->setOutputFormat("html");
            $ih = new java( "org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.HTMLServerImageHandler");
            $taskOptions->setImageHandler($ih);
            $taskOptions->setEnableAgentStyleEngine(true);
            $taskOptions->setBaseImageURL($imageURLPrefix . session_id());
            $taskOptions->setImageDirectory($here . "/images/" . session_id());
            $task->setRenderOption( $taskOptions );
            $task->run();
            $task->close();
         }
      catch (JavaException $e) {
            echo $e; //"Error Calling BIRT";
          }
      echo $outputStream;
    }
}
?>
```

So how to make the report support utf-8 encoding ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know PHP, but this could just be a problem of your encoding HTTP header. What does the HTML source generated by BIRT look like.
Does it contain a `<meta charset="xxx"/>` tag? 
If it does, this should match the `Content-Encoding` HTTP header (sent by your server, probably settable with PHP).